# Format date value as YYYYMM00

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to have it in this format `yyyymm00` in destination table (`20091000`). I'm using this

```
REPLACE(CAST(LEFT((invoice_date), 8) AS Nvarchar(20)), '-', '')
```

but its not getting me what I want it's giving me `oct 1 2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following :

```
Convert( Int, Convert( Varchar(6), invoice_date, 112 ) ) + '00'
```

Also, using :

```
Convert( Int, Convert( Varchar(8), invoice_date, 112 ) )
```

Returns : YYYMMDD.